# Wrapping NavigationRail in Focus breaks D-Pad selection

Tags: flutter

I'm developing an app on Android TV, with a `NavigationRail`. When the user selects the rail with the D-Pad, I'd like the rail to expand. If you've used the Disney+ or BBC Sounds apps on Android TV, you'll know what I'm trying to do.

I wrapped it in a `Focus` widget:

```dart
Focus(
  onFocusChange: (hasFocus) {
    setState(() { _extendNavigationRail = hasFocus; });
  },
  child: NavigationRail(
    extended: _extendNavigationRail,
    // ...
```

But when I do this, I can no longer use the D-Pad to select the items in the rail.

How do I get the focus to work properly within the rail? Or is there a better way to manage the extended state of the rail when it's selected with the D-Pad?

Answer (score 2):

Set the property of Focus `skipTraversal: true`. It helped me